# Try to merge Cache and use "invalidatesTags" both at "createApi" of Redux Toolkit in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I try to merge "Cache" and use "invalidatesTags" both in "createApi", but just one can working.

Merge cache working fine, but invalidatesTags in DeleteCollection for querySelect return nothing to merge or delete. Same problem with create but i temporarily fix it.

Can anyone help me. Thanks so much

Here is my createApi:

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import config from '../../config.json';
const API_URL = config.API_URL;
const merchant = config.MERCHANT_NAME;
const store = config.STORE;

import {Collection} from '../../models/Collection.model';

interface ListResponse<T> {
  offset: number;
  count: number;
  data: T[];
}
export const collectionApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'collectionApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${API_URL}/merchants/${merchant}/stores/${store}/`,
  }),
  tagTypes: ['Collections'],
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getAllCollections: builder.query<ListResponse<Collection>, any>({
      query: ({offset, limit}) => {
        let filter = encodeURIComponent(
          JSON.stringify({
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
          }),
        );
        return {
          url: `collections?filter=${filter}`,
        };
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, page) => {
        if (result) {
          return [
            ...result.data.map(({id}) => ({type: 'Collections' as const, id})),
            {type: 'Collections', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST'},
          ];
        } else {
          return [{type: 'Collections', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST'}];
        }
      },
      serializeQueryArgs: ({queryArgs, endpointDefinition, endpointName}) => {
        return endpointName;
      },
      merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
        if (newItems.offset == currentCache.offset) {
          if (
            newItems.count > currentCache.count &&
            newItems.offset == currentCache.count
          ) {
            currentCache.data = currentCache.data.concat(newItems.data);
          } else if (currentCache.data == null) {
            currentCache.data = newItems.data;
          }
          currentCache.offset = newItems.offset;
          currentCache.count = newItems.count;
        } else if (newItems.offset > currentCache.offset) {
          currentCache.data = currentCache.data.concat(newItems.data);
          currentCache.offset = newItems.offset;
          currentCache.count = newItems.count;
        }
      },
      forceRefetch({currentArg, previousArg}) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg;
      },
    }),
    createCollection: builder.mutation<Collection, Partial<any>>({
      query: data => ({
        url: `collections/`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, data) => {
        return [
          {type: 'Collections', id: result?.id},
          {type: 'Collections', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST'},
        ];
      },
    }),
    updateCollection: builder.mutation<Collection, Partial<any>>({
      query: ({data, id}) => ({
        url: `collections/${id}`,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, {id}) => [
        {type: 'Collections', id},
        {type: 'Collections', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST'},
      ],
    }),
    deleteCollection: builder.mutation<{success: boolean; id: number}, number>({
      query: id => ({
        url: `collections/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, id) => [
        {type: 'Collections', id},
        {type: 'Collections', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST'},
      ],
    }),
  }),
});

// Export hooks for usage in functional components
export const {
  useGetAllCollectionsQuery,
  useCreateCollectionMutation,
  useUpdateCollectionMutation,
  useDeleteCollectionMutation,
} = collectionApi;
```

Here is where i used:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native-bidirectional-infinite-scroll';
import ButtonSmall from '../../components/ButtonSmall';
import theme from '../../core/theme';
import {Icon} from '@rneui/themed';
import {
  useCreateCollectionMutation,
  useDeleteCollectionMutation,
  useGetAllCollectionsQuery,
} from '../../redux/services/collection';

const CollectionManagement = ({navigation}: any) => {
  //for infinite scroll
  const [offset, setOffset] = React.useState(0);
  const [limit, setLimit] = React.useState(10);

  //get collection
  const {
    data: allCollectionsData,
    error,
    isError,
    isLoading,
    refetch,
  } = useGetAllCollectionsQuery({offset: offset, limit: limit});

  const onStartReached = async () => {
    // console.log('reload');
    // await setOffset(0);
    // await refetch();
    return;
  };

  const onEndReached = async () => {
    if (allCollectionsData) {
      if (offset + limit > allCollectionsData.count) {
        await setOffset(allCollectionsData.count);
      } else {
        await setOffset(offset + limit);
      }
    } else {
      await setOffset(offset + limit);
    }
    await refetch();
    return;
  };
  //end infinite scroll

  const total = allCollectionsData?.count;
  const collectionList = allCollectionsData?.data;

  //delete collection
  const [
    deleteCollection,
    {data: dataDelete, error: errorDelete, isSuccess: isSuccessDelete},
  ] = useDeleteCollectionMutation();

  //create collection
  const [
    createCollection,
    {data: dataCreate, error: errorCreate, isSuccess: isSuccessCreate},
  ] = useCreateCollectionMutation();

  const deleteCollectionHandle = (id: any) => {
    Alert.alert('Thông báo', 'Bạn có chắc chắn muốn xoá danh mục này?', [
      {
        text: 'Không',
        onPress: () => {},
      },
      {
        text: 'Có',
        onPress: () => {
          deleteCollection(id);
        },
      },
    ]);
  };

  const doubleCollection = (data: any) => {
    let newData = {
      name: data.name,
      position: Number(data.position),
      description: data.description,
      internalName: data.internalName,
    };
    createCollection(newData);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Danh sách danh mục</Text>
        <Text style={styles.total}>Tổng số bản ghi: {total} </Text>
        <ButtonSmall
          title="Thêm mới"
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('CollectionCreate');
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <View
            style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={collectionList}
            onEndReached={onEndReached}
            onStartReached={onStartReached}
            keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id}
            renderItem={(data: any) => {
              let item = data.item;
              let url = item.preview;
              if (url === '') {
                url = 'https://petitemaika.com/brand.png';
              }
              return (
                <View key={item.id} style={styles.item}>
                  <View style={styles.info}>
                    <Image source={{uri: url}} style={styles.image} />
                    <View style={styles.detail}>
                      <Text
                        style={styles.itemName}
                        ellipsizeMode="middle"
                        numberOfLines={2}>
                        {item.name}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={styles.itemName}
                        ellipsizeMode="middle"
                        numberOfLines={1}>
                        Tên rút gọn: {item.internalName}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={styles.itemName}
                        ellipsizeMode="middle"
                        numberOfLines={3}>
                        Mô tả: {item.description}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={styles.itemName}
                        ellipsizeMode="middle"
                        numberOfLines={2}>
                        Thứ tự: {item.position}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.action}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate('CollectionEdit', item);
                      }}>
                      <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sửa</Text>
                        <Icon
                          name="pencil"
                          type="ionicon"
                          color={'white'}
                          size={20}
                        />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
                        doubleCollection(item);
                      }}>
                      <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Nhân bản</Text>
                        <Icon
                          name="copy"
                          type="ionicon"
                          color={'white'}
                          size={20}
                        />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
                        deleteCollectionHandle(item.id);
                      }}>
                      <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Xoá</Text>
                        <Icon
                          name="trash"
                          type="ionicon"
                          color={'white'}
                          size={20}
                        />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  header: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.BACKGROUND,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 5,
  },
  body: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.BACKGROUND,
  },
  //text styles
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: theme.colors.BLACK,
  },
  total: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: theme.colors.BLACK,
  },
  itemName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: theme.colors.BLACK,
  },

  //collection styles
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    borderColor: theme.colors.GREY,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  info: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
  },
  action: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginEnd: 10,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.PRIMARY,
    borderRadius: 7,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 3,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: theme.colors.WHITE,
    marginEnd: 5,
  },
  detail: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
});

export default CollectionManagement;
```